# C# - Windows Service, thread, timer - not run

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, timer

This is my code for Windows Service...but unfortunately, the method myTimer_Elapsed() is invoked only when at least 60 sec. after starting the service. Why not start immediately after switching service?

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private System.Threading.Thread myWorkingThread;
    private System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myWorkingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(PrepareTask);
        myWorkingThread.Start();
    }

    private void PrepareTask()
    {
        myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        myTimer.Interval = 60000;
        myTimer.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ..my code to prepare binary db files
    BinaryDB rdr = new BinaryDB();
    rdr.ReadFile(...)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the timer interval is set to 1 minute. See the below code in PrepareTask

```
myTimer.Interval = 60000;
```

You can set it to any appropriate value. or if you want your code to return once at the start and then after every 60 seconds than you should call it once in `OnStart` method. Like

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Do other initialization stuff...
    EvalutateChangeConditions ();
    // Create the thread and tell it what is to be executed.
    myWorkingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(PrepareTask);

    // Start the thread.
    myWorkingThread.Start();
}
```